# What is the right tool in GCP for building code pipelines?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, gcp-ai-platform-training

What is the right tool in GCP for building pipelines of code blocks. We should be able to drag, connect/disconnect nodes and enable/disable pipelines. I've tried to demonstrate in the picture below

[image]

1. create code blocks and connect between each (desired ones).
2. enable/disable pipelines. (for eg: enable the light-pink colored pipeline)
3. ability to Supply input (upload).
4. ability to view output (download, or see on the GUI itself).

I've read Apache airflow (cloud Composer) provides similar kind of functionality. But I would like to know if that is really the right tool for the requirement I mentioned above.

Comment: Other considerations might be NodeRED and Cloud Data Fusion.  To the best of my knowledge, Composer (Airflow) requires "coding" to achieve the pipeline and I think I am hearing you say you want a GUI based solution.  I am sensing that you are wanting to build an ETL pipeline and there are a number of 3rd party products that will run on GCP that achieve those goals.

Comment: @Kolban To make it clear, each node will be a python code that does a function. So does the all the options you suggested allow that?

Comment: Ahh ... no ... I was thinking that what you wanted was a visual workflow composition where the building blocks were "blocks of function" and not "actual" code functions in python.  I'm not aware of any "visual composition" tools that allow you to visually wire together Python functions/fragments.  Tools like NodeRED, Data Fusion and others allow us to visually wire together composable "blocks" of function rather than actual code fragments.  The closest (in my mind) would be NodeRED ... however that is Javascript focused rather than Python.

Comment: @Salih Have look on [this](https://codilime.com/blog/best-ci-cd-pipeline-tools-you-should-know/) . You have not tried GCP own cloud build?